# After booting, the screen is black. The "select user" button and password are not visible

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup

I just upgraded from 18.04.4 to 20.04.01. After booting the screen just goes black and I can only see the white mouse arrow at the lower right corner. The "user" and password areas are not visible at all, all is black.

I have done two things in order to start Ubutu: 1) Re-boot (alt + ImpSc + SUB) or just turn off by pressing the O button, and maybe will work as normal. 2) pressing enter (as to select user) and typing my password (as it where visible) and then enter. That works, but I do all on a black screen.

This is a Lenovo Ideapad L340, Ryzen 7

I tried to find an answer at ["My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)  but I couldn't find it there.
Many answers there are very old and that makes me doubt if that is still applicable now (I'm just a user, not an expert)
I clicked in "If an update or something else caused your problem" then "ATI/AMD Users" but the problem described under that point is different.

Any one knows what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No I couldn't find it there. 
Many answers are very old, from Ubuntu 11 and that makes me doubt if that is still applicable now.
I clicked in "If an update or something else caused your problem" then "ATI/AMD Users" but the problem described under that point is different.